# How to distinguish between "document" and "documentation"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I am wondering when we could use documentation instead of document?

Comment: "Document" means a specific collection of words you can point to, either sitting on a table or in a computer.  Eg, a book or manual.  "Documentation" means a somewhat looser collection of words, possibly scattered across a desk or across the interweb.

Comment: "Why is a raven like a writing desk?" —The Mad Hatter

Comment: Your question would attract more questions, and perhaps some helpful answers, if you looked up these two words in a dictionary, then quoted those very definitions (with a link back to the dictionary) in your question, with a note or comment on what confuses you about them.

Answer (score 1):

*Document*:

> a piece of written, printed, or electronic matter that provides
>   information or evidence or that serves as an official record. (Oxford
>   Dictionaries Online)

*Documentation*:

> 1. Material that provides official information or evidence or that serves
>      as a record. (Oxford Dictionaries Online)
> 2. The process of classifying and annotating texts, photographs, etc.
>      (Oxford Dictionaries Online)

The word *document* and *documentation* can be used as the synonyms because both first meanings in the dictionary cover each other. For example, they can be synonyms in the legal context:

> What is most needed is a clear explanation of the particular point on
>   which evidence is sought; the model form includes requests for
>   summaries of the parties' positions and suggests that relevant
>   **documentation** (court orders, pleadings) might be attached; but these
>   should be restricted to matters illuminating the particular request
>   for evidence and should not seek to rehearse the whole case. (the BNC)

Here we can change *documentation* with *documents*. Of course *documentation* contains the connotation of several documents or a collection of documents.

Answer (score 0):

**documentation**

- Your driver's license is documentation of your age, address, and that you have passed the tests required to drive a car.

**[document](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=document%20meaning&gbv=2&oq=document%20meaning&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0l7j0i22i30l3.797.3687.0.3953.16.11.0.0.0.0.500.1688.2-3j1j0j1.5.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..11.5.1688.Pc2y4LK2xr8)**

- a piece of written, printed, or electronic matter
- Document comes from the Latin verb meaning "to teach," so a document instructs you with the information it contains.
- Legal documents such as contracts contain instructions on how the people signing it will act.